# how to format the HTML string

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

What i want to do is to format the HTML text, so it would display in rows.

`name`and `age` (text) should be bold, and properly formatted in rows. How can i do this ?

```
Ext.getCmp('ex').push({
    title: 'Good Morning',
    html: 'name ' + frame + ' age : '+ lname 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just... HTML. So you would do it just how you normally would:

```
Ext.getCmp('ex').push({
    title: 'Good Morning',
    html: '<div><b>name</b>: ' + frame + '</div><div><b>age</b>: ' + lname + '</div>'
});
```

To improve code readability, I generally create an Array then `join` it:

```
Ext.getCmp('ex').push({
    title: 'Good Morning',
    html: [
        '<div>',
            '<b>name</b>: ' + frame,
        '</div>',
        '<div>',
            '<b>age</b>: ' + lname,
        '</div>'
    ].join('')
});
```